AWS Distro for OpenTelemetry Lambda Ignoring traceparent from SQS Trigger Message
I'm using ADOT/OTEL (arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:901920570463:layer:aws-otel-python-amd64-ver-1-21-0:1) to generate telemetry for ingestion into Honeycomb from AWS Lambda (Python).  On the whole, this works fine.  However, there is a case where a containerized Lambda function is being triggered by an SQS message.  Every time it's invoked, the span ID embedded in the traceparent message attribute (OTEL_PROPAGATORS is set to tracecontext on the function) is being ignored, and the span for the Lambda invocation being sent to Honeycomb has a parent span ID which doesn't refer to anything else in the system, so the root span for the Lambda invocation is absent.
